# How to access all Qt widgets with a promotion in a for loop?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am using Qt with [QCustomPlot](https://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/introduction),
I wish to access all my plots (Qt widget promoted to QCustomPlot) to modify their colors in a loop.
I have more than 30 plots in my app, I crated them one by one but 200 lines to modify their color is so painful so I want to use something like the method I used to modify the font on all my other widgets :

```
foreach (QWidget *widget, QApplication::allWidgets()) {
    widget->setFont(f);
    widget->update();
}
```

so it would look like :

```
for(QCustomPlot *widget : QCustomPlot::AllPlots()) {
widget->xAxis->setLabelColor(colcode);
}
```

but of course QCustomPlot::AllPlots() don't exist and nothing in the doc looks like it.
Any idea how I could modify the color of all my plots at once ?

Thank you a ton !

Comment: `auto children = parent->findChildren<QCustomPlot*>();` may do what you want. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren)

Comment: You could store pointers to the plots in a vector (`QVector<QCustomPlot*>`), then iterate over the vector. This would avoid having to dynamically cast from `QObject` every time. You may also want to read up on [qobject_cast](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast)

Comment: Thanks I used :
auto children = this->findChildren<QCustomPlot*>();
  foreach(QCustomPlot *widget ,children) {
and it works perfectly :D